# Are we allowed to pass $event as a parameter in a function called by ngStyle?

Tags: angular, typescript, function

My html is:

```
<div *ngFor="let dates of the_list">
    <p  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': changeColor($event)}" [ngClass]="{ 'text-white':(the_list.indexOf(dates))>4 }">{{dates}}</p>
</div>
```

and ts function is:

```
changeColor(event: any){
    this.temp=(<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    if(this.the_list.indexOf(this.temp)===5)
    {
      return 'blue'
    }
    else
    {
      return ''
    }
  }
```

It says:ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Am I not allowed to pass $event as a paramter?

Comment: There is no `$event` in the context of the call to `changeColor`. `$event` is available when you have an event handler such as `<button.... (click)="clickHandler($event)">`. You can for example call `changeColor(dates)`.

Comment: What would you expect the event to be in this case? This can be solved in the template alone by using the index on the ngFor loop.

Comment: @MikeOne thank you. Yes, there's no event, didn't think of it. I did solve it like you mentioned, but just wanted to know about this alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let i = index` like this:

```js
<div *ngFor="let dates of the_list; let i = index">
  <p [ngStyle]="{'background-color': i == 5 ? 'blue' : ''}" [ngClass]="{ 'text-white': i > 4 }">
{{dates}}</p>
</div>
```

It is better to avoid using functions in HTML.
Angular will call `function()` every time change detection runs and compare if the previous result is the same as the current result.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a method to determine the styling by passing the index at each iteration. This can be achieved as illustrated below. The `$event` cannot be accessed in this way because this is usually used with the invocation of an event. Such as a click, hover, key up and etc...

Try this:

In `template file`

```
<div *ngFor="let dates of the_listl let i = index">
    <p  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': changeColor(i)}" [ngClass]="{ 'text-white':(the_list.indexOf(dates))>4 }">{{dates}}</p>
</div>
```

In the `ts` file

```
changeColor(index: number){  
    if(index===5)
    {
      return 'blue'
    }
    else
    {
      return ''
    }
  }
```